# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}dk k^{d-2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_0\frac1{k_0^2-E^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am considering the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dk k^{d-2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_0\frac1{k_0^2-E^2},
$$
where: $k$ is real; $E=\sqrt{k^2+z}$; and $z$ is complex.
Using standard circuit integration one finds*
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_0\frac1{k_0^2-E^2}=\pi i\frac{\mathrm{sign}(\Im E)}{E}.
$$
Now, since $k^2>0$, if $\Re z>0$ one has $\mathrm{sign}(\Im E)=\mathrm{sign}(\Im z)$, and the integral in $k$ can be done to yield the final result
$$
\frac{i\sqrt\pi}{2}\mathrm{sign}(\Im z)z^{d/2-1}\Gamma(1-d/2)\Gamma((d-1)/2).
$$
But what about the case in which $\Re z<0$? It looks to me that in this case the relative sign of $\Re z$ and $k^2$ comes into play, but I cannot figure out what the result would be.

(* Mathematica gives me $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_0\frac1{k_0^2-E^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{-k^2-z}}$ whenever $k$ is real and $z$ complex, so no relative sign of real parts to be considered and problem solved; but is that true?)

Comment: How do you define square root of a complex number? Or even negative numbers? Why $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and not $-i$?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty k^{d-2} (\cdot)\,dk=\int_{k^2+\text{Re}(z)<0} k^{d-2} (\cdot)\,dk+\int_{k^2+\text{Re}(z)>0} k^{d-2} (\cdot)\,dk$$

Comment: @Andrei I have been putting the square root cut on the negative real axis. Do you think that is an issue?

Comment: @MarkViola I understand the identity there; but I don't get how it helps unless we know the value of two of the integrals (and we know only one, and only when Re(z)>0)